# remove an utf-8 text in string with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I try to remove an UTF-8 link in stirng

```
  $old = array("سایت (english) :");

        $new   = array('');
        $string = str_replace($old, $new, $string);
```

but no success ...can somebody please tell me my mistake?

Note I can remove pure non-english or pure english but not both in one text

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: the old text! I exactly send the text to the function and it returm me old text...without any change

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
 $string =  mb_convert_encoding ($string, 'UTF-8');
 $old    = array (mb_convert_encoding ("سایت (english) :", 'UTF-8'));
 $new    = array ('');
 $string = str_replace ($old, $new, $string);
```